# How to restrict kms:TagResource in AWS policy only to creation of new key, preventing tagging of existing keys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms, aws-policies

When you create a AWS KMS key you can provide tags for it. Creation alone needs kms:CreateKey permission, for providing the tags during the creation you need the  kms:TagResource permission in addition. - **I want to write a policy which only allows the creation of a KMS key if a certain marker tag is set AND it should not be allowed to use the kms:TagResource permission to add that marker tag to other *existing* keys.** How to do that? Thus, I would then be able to restrict other KMS permissions of that policy to only keys having that tag after that and a policy's user would not be allowed to add that marker tag to other keys which they should not be allowed to operate on